# How to know $f$ is a surjective submersion starting from $f^*$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

It is a well known fact that a smooth map $f:M\longrightarrow N$ between smooth manifolds (with some aditional hypothesis) is equivalent to a morphism of algebras $f^*:C^\infty(N)\longrightarrow C^\infty(M)$.

Which conditions should we have on $f^*:C^\infty(N)\longrightarrow C^\infty(M)$ in order to assure the corresponding smooth map $f:M\longrightarrow N$ is a surjective submersion?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want, but a map is a surjective submersion if and only if it admits local sections.

Comment: But how do you translate this fact algebraicly (that is, using the induced morphism $f^*$?)